# margin of text doesn't display corectly on different screens

Tags: android, text, screens

When I work on one android device and set the marginLeft of a text it looks good.
Then I connect another device and the margin is screwed up....

How can I make sure text (and also sizes of buttons) are displayed correctly on ALL android devices.

BTW yeah I'm allready using 'dp'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

          <ImageView 
              android:id="@+id/speler_image"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="159dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

          <ImageView 
              android:id="@+id/speler_infoblock"
              android:src="@drawable/playerinfoblock"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="107dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              android:layout_marginTop="159dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:text="Positie:"
                              android:textSize="17dp" 
                              android:textColor="#0096d6"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:id="@+id/spelerPositie"
                              android:text="0"
                              android:textSize="32dp" 
                              android:textColor="#01428b"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
                              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                              android:paddingRight="330dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:text="Score:"
                              android:textSize="16dp" 
                              android:textColor="#0096d6"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:id="@+id/spelerScore"
                              android:text="0"
                              android:textSize="16dp" 
                              android:textColor="#01428b"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
                              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                              android:paddingRight="160dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:text="Dagscore:"
                              android:textSize="16dp" 
                              android:textColor="#0096d6"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:id="@+id/spelerDagscore"
                              android:text="0"
                              android:textSize="16dp" 
                              android:textColor="#01428b"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
                              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                              android:paddingRight="160dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:text="Hole:"
                              android:textSize="16dp" 
                              android:textColor="#0096d6"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="280dp" />

                          <ImageView
                              android:src="@drawable/holeround"
                              android:layout_width="45dp"
                              android:layout_height="44dp"
                              android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
                              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                              android:paddingRight="7dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:id="@+id/spelerHole"
                              android:text="0"
                              android:textSize="24dp" 
                              android:textColor="#000000"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
                              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                              android:paddingRight="14dp" />

                          <ImageView
                              android:id="@+id/plaatsReactie"
                              android:src="@drawable/plaats_reactie"
                              android:layout_width="149dp"
                              android:layout_height="42dp"
                              android:scaleType="fitXY"
                              android:layout_marginTop="224dp"
                              android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

                          <TextView
                              android:text="Plaats reactie"
                              android:textSize="15dp" 
                              android:textColor="#0096d6"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="233dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="306dp" />

          <LinearLayout 
              android:background="#034489"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop="266dp" />

                           <ImageView
                              android:id="@+id/clickBiografie"
                              android:layout_width="100dp"
                              android:layout_height="47dp"
                              android:scaleType="fitXY"
                              android:layout_marginTop="266dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:text="Biografie"
                              android:textSize="17dp" 
                              android:textColor="#FFF"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="278dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="14dp" />

                           <ImageView
                              android:id="@+id/clickScore"
                              android:layout_width="100dp"
                              android:layout_height="47dp"
                              android:scaleType="fitXY"
                              android:layout_marginTop="266dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:text="Score"
                              android:textSize="17dp" 
                              android:textColor="#FFF"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="278dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="127dp" />

                           <ImageView
                              android:id="@+id/clickReacties"
                              android:layout_width="100dp"
                              android:layout_height="47dp"
                              android:scaleType="fitXY"
                              android:layout_marginTop="266dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="200dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:text="Reacties"
                              android:textSize="17dp" 
                              android:textColor="#FFF"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="278dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="220dp" />

                           <ImageView
                              android:id="@+id/clickTwitter"
                              android:layout_width="100dp"
                              android:layout_height="47dp"
                              android:scaleType="fitXY"
                              android:layout_marginTop="266dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="300dp" />

                          <TextView
                              android:text="Twitter"
                              android:textSize="17dp" 
                              android:textColor="#FFF"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_marginTop="278dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="324dp" />


          <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/biografieLayout"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop="313dp">

              <ImageView
                  android:src="@drawable/hole_infoline"
                  android:layout_width="375dp"
                  android:layout_height="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

              <TextView
                  android:text="Country"
                  android:textSize="16dp" 
                  android:textColor="#0096d6"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/countryText"
                  android:textSize="16dp" 
                  android:textColor="#FFF"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="160dp" />

              <ImageView
                  android:src="@drawable/hole_infoline"
                  android:layout_width="375dp"
                  android:layout_height="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

              <TextView
                  android:text="Date of Birth"
                  android:textSize="16dp" 
                  android:textColor="#0096d6"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/dobText"
                  android:textSize="16dp" 
                  android:textColor="#FFF"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="160dp" />

              <ImageView
                  android:src="@drawable/hole_infoline"
                  android:layout_width="375dp"
                  android:layout_height="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

              <TextView
                  android:text="Height / Weight"
                  android:textSize="16dp" 
                  android:textColor="#0096d6"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/heightweightText"
                  android:textSize="16dp" 
                  android:textColor="#FFF"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="160dp" />

              <ImageView
                  android:src="@drawable/hole_infoline"
                  android:layout_width="375dp"
                  android:layout_height="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

              <TextView
                  android:text="Turned Pro"
                  android:textSize="16dp" 
                  android:textColor="#0096d6"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/turnedProText"
                  android:textSize="16dp" 
                  android:textColor="#FFF"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="160dp" />

          </RelativeLayout>


          <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/scoreLayout"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop="313dp">

          </RelativeLayout>


          <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/reactiesLayout"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop="313dp">

          </RelativeLayout>


          <ScrollView
              android:id="@+id/twitterLayout"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop="313dp">

          </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show us your code please . So we can try to solve your problem

Comment: in your xml file there are two tabs namely:xml file and graphical layout.Any change you made will be seen there for every device in grphical layout.you can see in dropdown list which appears on the top of the palette

Comment: by implemeting your code i came to know that your question is obvious.but you are doing wrong.Android supports multi screen resolution so this will effect devices having small screen sizes.you are using Relative Layout but dont know have to implement it in a proper manner

Comment: so how do I make it work on other screens too then?

Comment: have you referred RelativeLayout in android.developer.com

Answer (score 0):

You can only be sure it displayed properly by testing. You can do some pre testing through eclipse. If you open the xml in eclipse you can click on "graphical layout" and then you can change the phone (screen size) you get a preview on.

If you want your layout to take % of the screen use linearlayout as parent and use weights for defining the percentage the views should take of the screen.

You say you have problems with your margins, this makes no sense as the margins will be what you define them to. So I assume your saying your can't get everything to align properly how you want it too... If that is the case you should use some kind of anchor point and then define the other layouts accordingly. You could for example create a container view (linear/relative etc.) inside your parent view and have that container centered.